# How to change delimiter in csv using icefaces data exporter

Tags: java, icefaces, icefaces-1.8, icefaces-2

I like to know how can i replace  delimiter in csv file generated by data exporters from icefaces.

I am using icefaces 2.0-Beta1.

Answer (score 0):

A little late i guess, but you can use a custom Exporter:

http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=aceMenu&exp=dataExporterCustom

Whith this you can customize the output format to your needs.